# visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio

when i run my c code in visual studio code this appears on the screen :

```
cd "c:\Users\DELL\Desktop\c c++\" ; if ($?) { gcc test.c -o test } ; if ($?) { .\test }
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find crt2.o: No such file or directory
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

could you please help me.
note:i have installed mingw

my code is so simple (i am a beginner ) the expected result is :
hello world

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it, like for example write a more relevant and suitable title that summarizes the problem you have.

Comment: As for your problem, please take some time to [read the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). And make sure your installation of MinGW is complete, as it currently seems to be missing some things.